# How to use jquery to load external html data in a variable in phonegap

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Phonegap to create a small app.
I have an url that points to a server somewhere giving me a simple html that either has "Available" in its body or it has something else.

I am trying to write a jquery that would recognize that "Available" and populate the element with some information. For now it's enough that it shows the word "Available".

This is what I have for now, but it doesn't append anything to the paragraph:

```
    <p class="result">x</p>
    <script>
    $( "#result" ).load( "http://someurl.com", function() {
    $('p.result').append(result);
    });
    </script>
```

Thank you in advance,

Antonio

Comment: welcome to so. Is that server in your domain whitelist? Are you using CORS?

Comment: @Eric Since the external website that gives me the data is not mine, I'm not sure about CORS. I put <access origin="http://*.it1.hr" /> in my config.xml. I put it just before </widget>.

Comment: @Eric: I read up on CORS and I guess it would be a solution, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it. I am not very good with javascript and I basically don't understand it well.

Comment: You need to be able on the server end to declare that its resources will be accessed by a 3rd party.

Comment: So, basically, I could create my own php file on my own server that would act as a proxy, gathering data from their url and basically just copying the result to my own server - then give myself permisions to access that from the Phonegap app?

Comment: You could acquire data with a script yes then host the data and expose it to that client. But in this case, you might want to consider a token sytem on top of CORS

Comment: Well, this is getting complicated. Thank you for your replies and I'm sorry for not replying sooner, I was on my vacation.

I will try to implement something similar to what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

Do not complicate this. Just wrote:

```
<script>
  // $(function() { ... }); is the same as $(document).ready(function() { ... });
  // It calls the function only after DOM is ready for your manipulations.
  $(function() {
    $(".result").load("test.html");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it like this:

`<p class="result">x</p>
<script>  
$(".result").load("url");
$('p.result').append(result); 
);
</script>`

Unfortunately, does not work.

Comment: You should call it in `$(document).ready(...)`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: he's not loading a local file

Comment: If you loading an external file there is no reason to do it with incorrect JS.

Comment: If you have an error with CORS, you'd better to find another way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh: I was not using CORS. This is the first time I actually heard about it. Since I'm not very good with javascript, I have no idea on how to incorporate it. I moved my code in a $(document).ready(...) since I guess even if it doesn't work that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @MorteTM If you're trying to load something from another site, you're using [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). If owner of another site do not allow you to load his data as you loading, you could not do this.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh Okay, thanks. So now I get to choose whether to ask them to allow me to access the file or to make a proxy on my own server with permissions for my Phonegap app.

Comment: I do not know what are you actually trying to do. You could make static form on your side (not loading it every time). You could post data to their side or connect to their side via their API on your app-side. It's not so easy question. It's about your architecture.